# How to set console to default view eclipse

Tags: eclipse, console

I don't know how but I accidentally set my console view so it is in a separate window, how do I change it back to the default view?

I am using eclipse Luna.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the title of the view (`Console`) and drag it back into place. Or, click `Window` -> `Reset Perspective`.